# GET request issue

Tags: java, rest, postman, request-mapping

I have two REST endpoints.

**(1) get by ID number**

```
/api/{id} : PathParam
```

Example request: `/api/123`

and

**(2) get all data**

```
/api : QueryParam
```

Example request: `/api?id=123`

So when I send a request for a negative scenario `/api/`, it is routed to (2). But here I am expecting it to be routed to (1) as it is the expected result with the trailing `/`. Is my expectation wrong?

Comment: Is your negative scenario using a uri with a leading slash (/api/) or without one (api/)?

Comment: It is /api/ with both the sides.

Answer (score 2):

In the route `/api/{id}`, you are defining `id` as a required part of the URL. The URL `/api/` does not contain this required part. Therefore, the route `/api` will be used instead. Adding a final slash `/api/` does not change this.

Comment: But then it means the (2) is for QueryParams and not the Pathparam. So it is expected to throw invalid URL right?
Can you share any references which could help me to understand better?

Comment: No, you can mix required path parameters and (optional) query parameters. The routing works by looking at the shape of the URL only, ignoring the query string.